# How to select, update and insert Sql Server data from a c# forms app

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I'm new to .Net and c# and need to write a application that performs some automated hardware tests and records the results in a sql server 2000 database. I need basic functionality, like populating grids and combo boxes with sql data, filtering a list based on some user input, and inserting/updating sql data based on test results.
I'm wondering if there are any recommendations on the best way to go about this.
Datasets? LINQ? SqlConnection Class?

I'm comfortable writing sql statements and stored procedures and I have seen examples of calling sp's from c# but it that the best way to go?

Comment: You can do it all of those ways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use traditional ADO instead of LINQ since you are using SQL Server 2000.  While most LINQ operations work fine with 2000, [some do not](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/e9c2fa01-dc02-452e-b282-28a2dd1cf6d0/).

As far as finding good intro's to ADO.NET take a look at the examples in the MSDN documentation (which i find to be pretty good):

- [SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx)
- [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx)

[Here](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/02/19/binding-gridview-with-data---the-ado.net-way.aspx) is a good tutorial on using a GridView with ADO.NET

Comment: You posted this right while I was editing my answer to add the "simplest approach".  +1 for recommending traditional ADO. I agree completely.

Answer (score 3):

Stored Procedures are a good way to go. Parameterized queries are fine, too.  (both protect from SQL Injection if done properly.)  LINQ is good as well.

There are plenty of resources.  I like the videos here for beginners: http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx

However, to me, the simplest approach with the least amount of overhead is to use the standard [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx), and use it with an Update stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it all of those ways. It really comes down to what your particular use case is, and what your developers are capable of. LINQ is a more modern approach, but is an ORM, and ORM's can be dangerous if you don't understand the underlying abstraction. LINQ makes it easier to deal with data directly in your code. ADO.NET is an option to consider when you want straight SQL, parameterized queries, or stored procedures to a database. Stored procedures provide a decent seperation of concerns, in that you've abstracted the data-intensive functions to the database.

Really though any option will work, it's just a matter of weighing the pros and cons of each. Benefits and drawbacks for all.

Comment: +1 for "ORM's can be dangerous if you don't understand the underlying abstraction".